# Generating Lehmar code in linear time - bitset algorithm

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sequence

To generate the lexicographic index of a permutation, we generate first its Lehmar code - basically representation in the factorial number system. To do this, we take each element of the permutation and subtract the number of elements to the left that are less than it. How do you find the number of elements on the left that are lesser than a particular digit of the permutation? You can do it in linear time if you simply scan all of them. You can do it in logarithmic time if you store them in a Binary search tree. But there is also a way to do it in constant time. In the blog [here](https://medium.com/@benjamin.botto/sequentially-indexing-permutations-a-linear-algorithm-for-computing-lexicographic-rank-a22220ffd6e3), this is covered in the section "a linear algorithm". Quoting:

Let’s work through this algorithm by way of example, again using the permutation (2 0 1).

1. Start with a bitset of length 3, initialized to zero (000b).
2. The first element of the permutation is 2, so flip bit 2 of the bitset: 001b. As mentioned above, the first digit of the Lehmer code is always the same as the first digit of the permutation, 2 in this case.
3. The second element of the permutation is 0, so set bit 0 of the bitset: 101b. Right-shift the bitset by n - k, where n is 3, the number of elements in the permutation, and k is 0, the second element of the permutation. 101b >> (3-0) = 000b. Count the number of ones in the result (countOnes(000b) = 0), and subtract that from the element to get the Lehmer digit: 0 - 0 = 0.
4. The third element of the permutation is 1, so set bit 1 of the bitset: 111b. Right-shift: 111b >> (3-1) = 001b. Subtract the number of ones in the result from the element to get the Lehmer digit: 1 - countOnes(001b) = 1-1 = 0.
   As expected, the Lehmer code is 200.

I can see this works for that specific permutation, but I'm completely lost as to why it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see it this way: say we're in the position t of the permutation. until now, bit i in the bitset is 1 iff i is on the left of the current element. When you shift it n-k times to the right, what is left is the first k bits of the string (consider shifting all the way n times, then undoing it k times) so now we have some 0s and some 1s that each corresponds to a number less than the current element. Thus, all we need to do is to count 1s in the resulting string.